# best state management for video audio editor with flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-getx

I am trying to build an audio and video application, but I need a strong state management, so what is the best choice with flutter? Do I use Bloc or Getx, as I like the way GitX works, but I am not sure is the best choice or not?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter which **state management** you are going to use, I made some apps that play videos with different **state managements** and there is no difference at all in this particular case.